# Would monitors attached to my USB hub make my CPU run hotter?

Tags: display, usb, cpu

Would having 2 monitors attached to my USB hub (along with 1 monitor attached to the MiniDisplay port) contribute to the CPU getting hotter?

My MacBook:

- Core i5@2.5-GHz
- 16-GB of RAM
- 1 [HooToo 7 port USB hub](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0J2-0020-00012)
- 2 [Diamond USB Multi-Display Adapter](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/18085724156970829992?q=diamond%20uga%20usb%20to%20hdmi%20adapter%20newegg&prds=hsec:reviews&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhh8vKj6bVAhXn5YMKHY5rDjIQ4SsIDygC)
- the USB Display Adapters attach to [HP 2511x](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824176194) (25") and [Samsung S24D300](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA25V3U28267&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC-_-pla-_-Monitors%20-%20LCD%20Flat%20Panel-_-9SIA25V3U28267&gclid=CjwKCAjw2NvLBRAjEiwAF98GMfwtTnOwXO2htXugB5eet6xAAzJ8bisvwOIUmXKk-moKHzH0Pq2FZhoCz8EQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) (24")
- the MiniDisplay port monitor is [HNC iF281D](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824723002) (28")
- MacOS 10.11 (El Capitan)
- I installed [iStat](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/istat-3/id1151686606?mt=8) to monitor things.

I just read in some forum that the **CPU might overheat** with more than 1 external monitor???

I have been using this set-up for a few days. It is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you man, for publishing the answer.

Just as a follow up to the answer, it won´t make it run hotter, but it will consume some processing from your CPU (while compressing video) and mostly the GPU (for rendering the additional screens), this Wikipedia article tells exactly your answer and adds some context to it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayLink

> The DisplayLink network graphics technology is composed of Virtual
>   Graphics Card (VGC) software that is installed on a PC and a Hardware
>   Rendering Engine (HRE) embedded or connected to a display device. The
>   DisplayLink VGC software is based on a proprietary adaptive graphics
>   technology. The VGC software runs on a Windows, Mac OS X, Linux host
>   PC and takes information from the graphics adapter and compresses the
>   changes to the display from the last update and sends it over any
>   standard network including USB, Wireless USB, Ethernet, and Wi-Fi.
>   After receiving the data, the HRE then transforms it back into pixels
>   to be displayed on the monitor.

Comment: But, isn't "consuming processing power from your CPU" what causes a CPU to get hotter?

Comment: An intensive CPU process would cause an increase in temperature, but not at the level of compressing a signal and sending it through USB, that would just increase CPU consumption just between 1% and 3%.

Comment: You are totally correct. Why didn't I just use Activity Monitor to watch CPU usage? "DisplayLinkManager" is always less than a 10% load. iStat shows my CPU temp is within normal range. yeah. I think I'm good with using 2 of those USB adapters. I am so relieved.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

[USB graphics devices, like the USB-HDMI-DVI, are “virtual” devices where much of the heavy lifting is done by the CPU, by hooking into the graphics stack.](http://plugable.com/products/usb3-hdmi-dvi/)

Even so, I'll keep this set-up and monitor things with *iStat*. All I display is *MSFT Word* documents and stupid web pages. I think I'll be ok?

Sorry I did not do more research!